# one-dimensional distortion of rubber band algorithm

Tags: algorithm, distortion

Problem: I have a database result set of n. I want to have k < n index links to the results on a html page. There should be more index links near the cursor, have the user forward +5 is more probable than to forward +50

Idea is to have a number line on a rubber band with markings, if I put a weight on the cursor point and view from above I should have the index points.

[image]

Is there an easy algorithm for this?

Same problem would be for an index to forum messages.

Comment: What are 'index links to the results'? What does 'forward' mean in this context?

Comment: If you have a resultpage_1.html up to resultpage_1000.html, s.th. like
<a href="resultpage_10.html" >10</a>

Comment: You are talking about pagination. Your can't show all page links, so you want to show the first, last and those close to the active page, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: In the sample in the image I'd like to link to 1,3,4 maybe 8, and ten

Comment: no link to the first element 0? Perhaps you could include a good / expected output for the given pagination in your question.

Answer (score 0):

@le_m Thanks for pointing me to pagination.

So I found

[Smart pagination algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163809/smart-pagination-algorithm)

https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-end-of-pagination/

http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Pagination

I ended with implementing it myself in Java as
https://github.com/weberjn/jBM/blob/master/model/src/main/java/de/jwi/jbm/model/PagePosition.java

My original idea was too complicated.